# Add NFT Royalties Feature to a marketplace?

Tags: nft

###Checking if the NFT being sold on your marketplace implemented royalties###
Here is reply

```
bytes4 private constant _INTERFACE_ID_ERC2981 = 0x2a55205a;

function checkRoyalties(address _contract) internal returns (bool) {
    (bool success) = IERC165(_contract).supportsInterface(_INTERFACE_ID_ERC2981);
    return success;
}
```